# Can't get Error Message for when a user is not found to show up. It goes into infinite loading when searching

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes, passport.js

```
router.post('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
const { username } = req.body;
let errors = [];

User.find({ username: username }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (user.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
            if (user[i].username == username) {
                errors.push({ msg: 'Username Found! :)' });
                console.log("Username Found!");
            } 
            if(user[i].username !== username ) {
                errors.push({ msg: 'Username Not Found.. :(' });
                return res.redirect('dashboard');
            }
        }
        res.render('searchUser', {
            errors: errors,
            username
        });
    }
});
});
```

I can search for a user that exist in the Mongodb but when I try to type a user that does not exist, it loads forever. I want the error message to pop up and say that the user was not found. Similar to how I have the top if statement. I'm confused on what I am doing wrong as this User.find works with my sign up registration method but not this.